# The contacts from roster group not returned to client after Openfire upgrade to 3.8

Tags: upgrade, openfire

I was using JDBCGroupProvider with openfire 3.7.1 to pick groups from database and fill rosters using them by marking them as shared-roster-group in ofGroupProp table. This was working well. Last week I upgraded the server to openfire 3.8, after which contacts from shared roster groups stopped being sent to the clients. (As my users had friends from this shared roster group only, now the roster is empty for all users)
Anyone hit and resolved similar issue after an openfire upgrade ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same problem after upgrading from Openfire 3.7.1 to 3.8.2 only to find this unanswered question. After a little more searching, I discovered it was a caching problem. To clear the caches, go to **Server -> Cache Summary** on the **Admin Console** and check all the following:

- Group
- Group Metadata Cache
- Roster
- User

And then select **Clear Selected** at the bottom of the page. Might be over-kill on the caches, but it did the trick for me!